# Oracle Stored Proc- Can I return a composite TYPE consisting of number of other STRUCTs?

Tags: database, algorithm, plsql, oracle11g

I want to create a Stored Proc in Oracle(11g) which will fetch the data from 14-16 tables which are connected by FK.
The logic is as below-
1. Extract the Key from Main Table from the Input Params.
2. Extract data from all other tables using the key.

I also want to create Oracle types aligned to each table and composite TYPE which will contain all these Array of Types.

**Notes:**

1. Few tables may not have data for that Key.If data is missing in particular, I would return blank STRUCT for that table.
2. Some tables may have multiple rows for the given key.We will populate ARRAY of TYPE mapping to that table.

I am quite new to oracle programming. I want to understand, is it possible to return COMPOSITE TYPE from SP?
If not possible, Can I return multiple ARRAY of TYPEs from SP?

Comment: What is a STRUCT in pl/sql?  you can build a ref cursor and return whatever you want in it, or use a pl/sql collection. Go read [this book](http://freecomputerbooks.com/Oracle-PL-SQL-Programming-5th-Edition.html)

Comment: Its a Type- CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE XYZ AS OBJECT
                  (  col1 VARCHAR2 (2 BYTE),
                   col2 VARCHAR2 (10 BYTE)
                  )

Comment: Then edit your question and call it what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, composite types can be built in SQL and PL/SQL.  Here's an example using object types:

```
drop table table2;

create table table1(a number, b number);
create table table2(a number, b number);

create or replace type table1_type is object
(
    a number,
    b number
);

create or replace type table2_type is object
(
    a number,
    b number
);

create or replace type table1_nt is table of table1_type;
create or replace type table2_nt is table of table1_type;

create or replace type table_1_2_type is object
(
    table1 table1_nt,
    table2 table2_nt
);
```

`table_1_2_type` can now be used as a return type or an OUT type.

The type definitions are unfortunately very repetitive.  The %TYPE and %ROWTYPE operators do not work in SQL, and depending on how you use these objects they must be defined as SQL types.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that.  Let's say your type is XYZ_TYPE. You'd create your function (it'd have to be a function if you want to return a TYPE instance) as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XYZ_FUNC(pParm_1  IN NUMBER,  -- or whatever
                                    pParm_2  IN NUMBER)  -- etc, blah
  RETURN XYZ_TYPE
IS
  nVar_1  NUMBER;  -- or whatever
  tResult XYZ_TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- whatever

  RETURN tResult;
END XYZ_FUNC;
```

Share and enjoy.